# Convert String to UInt16 Objective-C

Tags: string, int, converters, uint16

I am facing the problem, that I can't convert an string or an int to an UInt16. This is my current code: `(UInt16)[[defaults stringForKey:@"port"] intValue]`  `[[defaults stringForKey:@"port"] intValue]` is `8080` and `(UInt16)[[defaults stringForKey:@"port"] intValue]` becomes `51075` which is wrong. Does anyone know to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer my selfe:

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *port = [defaults stringForKey:@"port"];
    UInt16 portNumber = [[formatter numberFromString:port] unsignedShortValue];
```

Comment: I think you should click on the tick to accept your own answer :D